# How to use tsconfig-paths with pm2?

Tags: pm2, nestjs, ts-node, tsconfig-paths

I'm trying to deploy my typescript project with pm2, but the argument seems not working correctly.

Here is ecosystem.config.yml:

```
apps:
  - name: 'node-app'
    script: './src/main.ts'
    interpreter: './node_modules/.bin/ts-node'
    # they dont't work correctly below.
    interpreter_args: '-r tsconfig-paths/register'
    # args: '-T -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts',
    # args: '-r ./node_modules/tsconfig-paths/register ./src/main.ts'
    # interpreter_args: ['--require=tsconfig-paths/register']
    # interpreter_args: '-P . -r ./node_modules/tsconfig-paths/register'
    kill_timeout: 10000
    instances: max
    exec_mode: cluster
    env:
      NODE_ENV: development
```

When I run pm2 start ecosystem.config.yml and check the logs then:

```
0|node-app | Error: Cannot find module '~framework/common/frame-util'
0|node-app |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
0|node-app |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
0|node-app |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
0|node-app |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
0|node-app |     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zhaolin/__CODES__/__PERSONAL__/charley-nest-starter/script/ci/src/solution/gateway/auth/auth.service.ts:5:1)
0|node-app |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
0|node-app |     at Module.m._compile (/Users/zhaolin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:473:23)
0|node-app |     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
0|node-app |     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/zhaolin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:476:12)
0|node-app |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

And my tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~framework/*":["src/framework/*"],
      "~solution/*":["src/solution/*"],
      "~business/*":["src/solution/business/*"],
      "~dto/*":["src/solution/dto/*"],
      "~entities/*":["src/solution/entities/*"],
      "~/*":["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

It seems that the paths alias are not working properly.
It works well without pm2(this is a nestjs project):

```
...
    "start": "rimraf dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
...
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe first build the project, and then run by pm2.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Aleksandr said you can first build the project using `tsc` and then run it using `node`, instead of `ts-node`.

Example:

1. In your script runner (within package.json) you can define:

```
  "build": "tsc",
  "runBuild": "pm2 start ecosystem.yml --only node-app"
```

2. In your `ecosystem.yml` you can define:

```
apps:
  - name: 'node-app'
    script: './dist/src/main.js'
    node_args: '-r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register'
    kill_timeout: 10000
    instances: max
    exec_mode: cluster
    env:
      NODE_ENV: development
```

3. To run:

```
$ npm run build
$ npm run runBuild
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

### In my case, I did resolve PM2 use with TS like the bellow

```js
  PM2 config file in the root folder: pm2.config.ts

// TS Setup
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'AppName',
            script: './app/index.ts',
        },
    ],
};

// JS setup
// module.exports = {
//     apps: [
//         {
//             name: 'AppName',
//             script: './dist/app/index.js',
//         },
//     ],
// };
```

### Here is my package.json scripts section

```js
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "test:ci": "jest",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache",
    "ts:dev": "ts-node-dev --poll app/index.ts",
    "start": "pm2 start  --interpreter ts-node-dev pm2.config.ts",
    "pm2:stop": "pm2 stop  --interpreter ts-node-dev pm2.config.ts",
    "js:dev": "npm run clean && npm run compile && node ./dist/app/index.js"
  },
```